# PHP Creating JSON array of arrays (data coming from MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i've been searching all over and can't get any solution to work...
this is my code, the problematic area is how to create 1 large array of per-sql-row array:
(the commented-out line is the one causing the error).

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM  `Orders` WHERE  `userID` = " . $objData->userid . " ORDER BY  `recievedDate` DESC LIMIT 10");
        $resArray = array();    
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_row())
            {
                $tempArr = array("orderid" => $row[0], "orderdate" => $row[2], "orderstatus" => $row[4]);
                //$resArray = array_push((array)$resArray, (array)$tempArr);  <== problematic line commented out
            }
            echo json_encode($resArray);        
        } else {                
            echo "";    
        }
```

thanks!

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this. A simple mistake can have disastrous consequences.

Comment: OK i will look into it. but this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to push your `$temparr` array to `$resArray` like this:

```
$resArray[] = $tempArr;
```

Note you could also use [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/array_push) if you really wanted to.

Not sure what all your query is returning, but did you know you could also just [get your query results as an array](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array) to begin with?

```
$resArray = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If your query is returning more than you need in your array, just limit the query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT orderid, orderdate, orderstatus FROM  `Orders` ...");
$resArray = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Done!

Comment: thanks! really helpful. i didnt know the fetch_array was useful when more then 1 row was returned.

Answer (score 2):

Beside other important aspect you are assigning the result of array_push `$resArray = array_push((array)$resArray, (array)$tempArr)`, so the `json_encode($resArray)` gets a number and not the array you need.